# How to use my custom ami and deploy ec2 instance using ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-ami

I am trying to use my custom ami which customer will be giving me often, I need to use that ami and deploy ec2 instance using that, The ami id will change whenever there will new ami given , 
Can you please help me with the playbook which i should be using in order to take my custom ami and deploy ec2 instance using that .

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the docs for [ec2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_module.html) module:

```
- ec2:
    key_name: mykey
    instance_type: t2.micro
    image: ami-123456
    wait: yes
    group: webserver
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
    assign_public_ip: yes
```

Just use your AMI ID.

If you don't want to hardcode id, you can use [ec2_ami_find](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_ami_find_module.html) module to search AMI by pattern and take latest, for example.